# Python regex not returning expected value

Tags: python, regex, string

Question:

Given a word, you need to judge whether the usage of capitals in it is right or not.

We define the usage of capitals in a word to be right when one of the following cases holds:

All letters in this word are capitals, like "USA".
All letters in this word are not capitals, like "leetcode".
Only the first letter in this word is capital if it has more than one letter, like "Google".
Otherwise, we define that this word doesn't use capitals in a right way.

My solution (using regex library)

import re

```
def detectCapitalUse(word):

    pattern = r'[A-Z]*|[A-Z]?[a-z]*'
    r = re.search(pattern, word)
    print r.group()
```

The first half of the pattern, `[A-Z]*` should match all uppercase letters OR the second part `[A-Z]?[a-z]*` should match any words that either start with one capital letter with the rest being lowercase or match a word with only lower case letters.

When I write the following testcases, I get unexpected answers

`detectCapitalUse("Flag")      Expected: Flag      Actual Value: F`

`detectCapitalUse("flag")      Expected: flag      Actual Value: Empty string`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Swap your ordering. `[A-Z]*` is matching and finishing the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something more like `r'[A-Z]?[a-z]+|[A-Z]+'`

The reason your pattern doesn't work as expected can be gleaned from the `re` module docs:

> As the target string is scanned, REs separated by `'|'` are tried from left to right. When one pattern completely matches, that branch is accepted.

So the `[A-Z]*` branch immediately matches on a single upper case character and that match is what's returned.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are having is related to the fact that this regex `[A-Z]*` starts the matching, then it stops before finishing for cases like `Flag`. Try to solve this by requiring `[A-Z]` to match at least two letters or more. Try this regex:

```
[A-Z]{2,}|[A-Z]?[a-z]*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/H2ExoN/1/

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the first requirement first: all letters are uppercase. Recall that `*` matches zero or more times, so can perfectly well match the empty string. That explains your second unexpected case above. Also be aware that `re.search()` matches anywhere in the string, so you'll need to exclude non-upper-case from the head and tail. One way to do this would be to match against the start and end of the pattern, and set a minimum match count to exclude the empty string:

`^[A-Z]{1,}$`

(Note that this will also match a single upper-case letter.)

The same considerations apply to your second case. So your combined pattern would be:

`^[A-Z]{1,}$|^[A-Z]?[a-z]{1,}$`

or alternately:

`^([A-Z]{1,}|[A-Z]?[a-z]{1,})$`

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep things simple: You can fix your solution by requiring it to match the entire string, which is what you meant anyway: `r"^([A-Z]*|[A-Z]?[a-z]*)$"` will work as you expected.

Comment: Interesting, that works. I would have expected the first part of the conditional to trivially match the empty string in the absence of upper-case characters. This should be the accepted answer as long as you don't care about excluding the empty string.

Comment: Thanks. The parentheses anchor the whole thing to start _and_ end, so it only matches the empty string if tested against `""`. Which is not a "word", so it's undefined behavior (and if one thinks about it, it is not *im*properly capitalized; in my opinion it should pass). But anyway it will work correctly on any _word_ tested, and more important it fixes the mystery where the OP was stuck-- what to do about the empty string they can decide and fix themselves. My point was to fix the problem, not rewrite the solution from scratch.